# Using Translation Strings As Array keys for multilanguage like Gettext msgid?

Tags: php, localization, multilingual

I made some tests to using translation strings as array keys like gettext msgid

Simple Example:

```
function translate( $str, $locale = 'en')
{
    // $languages = load_from_file(); will use fallowing var just for sample
    $languages =[
                'en'    => [
                                'Hello World' => 'Hello World',
                                'What time is it?' => 'What time is it?',
                                'What time is it now?' => 'What time is it now?',
                                'Supported symbols [. ? # $ , / * + - _ ]' => 'Simple supported symbols . ? # $ , / * + - _',
                            ],

                'de'    => [
                                'Hello World' => 'Hallo Welt',
                                'What time is it?' => 'Wie spät ist es?',
                                'What time is it now?' => 'Wie viel Uhr ist es jetzt?',
                                'Supported symbols [. ? # $ , / * + - _ ]' => 'Unterstützte Symbole [. ? # $, / * + - _]',
                            ]
            ];


      $lang = $languages[ $locale ];

    return $lang[ $str ] ?? 'Unknown String';

}

        echo translate( 'Supported symbols [. ? # $ , / * + - _ ]' );
        // returns "Unterstützte Symbole [. ? # $, / * + - _]"
        echo translate( 'What time is it?' );
        // returns "Wie spät ist es?"
```

What will advantages & disadvantages or can be anyproblem ? is it safe to use at all ?

Comment: I believe this will work well but be careful in the replace action. Say you have the string "what time is it" and also the string "what time is it now" you may end up with a semi translated string.

Comment: it is same on gettext too i thing. after some searches php arrays seems best for human reading, add/editing for multilanguage. Short keys are confusing mostly.